Multiplexer bug (CameralnputController + Touchpad)

        // the touchpad

        multiplexer.addProcessor(createGameUiDev.getStage()); 

        

        // Adds camera controls to the multiplexer

        multiplexer.addProcessor(camController);

    

        // Set the multiplexer as the main input handler

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);


When the touchpad is touched first, I can't move the camera at the same time. But when I move the camera first, I can move the touchpad at the same time. I want when the touchpad is touched first, I can also move the camera at the same time.I think the problem is that the camera only supports the first finger placed on the screen and not the second and third etc...
I tried to change the order of multiplexer.addProcessor but it didn't work. I set the touchpad and camera to false, but it didn't work. Instead of all that, when I move the joystick and then move the camera at the same time, the camera zooms in and out instead of moving properly.
